# How to access Java arrays in HTML code

Tags: java, html, servlets, server

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe program using HTML and Java. After user input, the server goes to the servlet, which puts the value back into the array and then redirects the server back to the HTML page.

HTML code (with Tic-Tac-Toe table that needs values to go in the entries):

```
<form action="servlet1" method="get">

<br><br> <table>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="0"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="1"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="2"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="3"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="4"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="5"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="6"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="7"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="8"> </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
<br><input type="submit" value="Turn Completed" />
 </form>
```

Java Servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/servlet1")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)     throws ServletException, IOException {

        String[] board = new String[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
            board[i] = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"input\" value=\"" + i + "\">";
        }



        int loc = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("input"));
        board[loc] = "X";

        resp.setStatus(resp.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        resp.setHeader("Location", "index.html");

    }
}
```

**How do I get the value of board in my Java code to transfer to the HTML page each time and render Xs based on user input? Is there any way to access board in the HTML program and use board[0], board[1] etc to fill the table values in the HTML code?**

Comment: If you want this to run entirely client-side, you could write it in JavaScript and throw away the servlet altogether.  Or if you want it running server-side, just use Java and/or JSP to draw whatever HTML you need.  You should probably choose which architecture you prefer before you go any further with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to form a response, here is a simple example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    // set content type
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    // get response writer
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    // build HTML code
    String htmlResponse = "<html>";
    htmlResponse += "<h2>This is my Response example:</h2>";    
    htmlResponse += "Some Text as an example.";
    htmlResponse += "</html>";

    // return response
    writer.println(htmlResponse);
}
```